# ESP8266 NodeMCU running out of memory while creating more than one https connections

Tags: c++, firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to make two parallel https connections to firebase real time database rest api using NodeMCU ESP-12E. I am using WiFiClientSecure for that purpose. I am getting an out of memory error. Are https connections that expensive or is there some problem with my code or is this some glitch of the WiFiClient library
This is the code that I am using:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";
const char* server = "[project id].[database location].firebasedatabase.app";
const int httpPort = 443;
WiFiClientSecure client1;
WiFiClientSecure client2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to WiFi
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Make HTTP GET request
  client1.setInsecure();
  if (!client1.connect(server, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("client1 connected");
  delay(10000);

  client2.setInsecure();
  if (!client2.connect(server, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("client2 connected");
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

This is the output and error log:

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 192.168.135.220
client1 connected

User exception (panic/abort/assert)
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Unhandled C++ exception: OOM

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffeb0 end: 3fffffd0 offset: 0010
3ffffec0:  c02ac026 c00ec004 000005d8 40204798  
3ffffed0:  c09dc09c 00000001 3fff0e1c 40202cb7
3ffffee0:  00000000 c00dc003 3fff000a 40202924
3ffffef0:  00000000 00000000 00000d60 3ffe882f  
3fffff00:  00000000 3fff6b84 3fff0e1c 40203165
3fffff10:  00000000 00004640 ee560418 00513b13
3fffff20:  00000000 00000000 00000034 00004640
3fffff30:  00003a98 3fff1454 3fff0e1c 402023aa  
3fffff40:  3fff696c 00002710 00001f2f 40204a15
3fffff50:  00000000 00001f2f 4c8b4395 00000001
3fffff60:  000001bb 3ffe882f 3fff0e1c 402032f1  
3fffff70:  40207df4 cfecba23 40207df4 cfecba23
3fffff80:  3fff0e1c 3ffee708 3ffee794 4020124c
3fffff90:  40207df4 dc87a8c0 feefeffe feefeffe
3fffffa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 3ffee848  
3fffffb0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee81c 40204abc
3fffffc0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3fffdab0 40100d15
<<<stack<<<

last failed alloc call: 40202CB7(1496)

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

last failed alloc caller: 0x40202cb7

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

tail 0
chksum 0x2e
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8
tail 0
chksum 0x2b
csum 0x2b
v0005d1a0
~ld
```

Also I am creating these connections to the same host and port and intend to use one of the connections for a GET stream and the other for GET and PUT requests